# Reproducible MATLAB System Error (simple code)

Tags: matlab

I am trying to run the pretty simple code given in file Assignment6.m which can be found here:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xs2m0arvv9lxydw/AAA6uLU75R-7Blv7GqOJaNGka?dl=0

however I get a MATLAB System Error under my system (it runs on others though). I reinstalled MATLAB without improvement though. I cannot post code here directly as it involves a small data sample that is given under the link above. Does anyone have an idea? Can you reproduce the error or does it run smooth on your PC? Here is the full error message:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Illegal instruction detected at Tue Jun 23 10:35:30 2015
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding      : Disabled
  Crash Mode          : continue (default)
  Current Graphics Driver: Unknown hardware 
  Default Encoding    : windows-1252
  Graphics card 1     : Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. ( 0x1002 ) AMD Radeon(TM) R5 M240 Version 13.302.1101.1004
  Graphics card 2     : Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. ( 0x1002 ) AMD Radeon(TM) R5 Graphics Version 13.302.1101.1004
  Host Name           : Andy
  MATLAB Architecture : win64
  MATLAB Root         : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a
  MATLAB Version      : 8.5.0.197613 (R2015a)
  OpenGL              : hardware
  Operating System    : Microsoft Windows 8.1
  Processor ID        : x86 Family 127 Model 48 Stepping 1, AuthenticAMD
  Virtual Machine     : Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System       : Version 6.3 (Build 9600)

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Illegal instruction

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 000000007cd88000  RBX = 000000007cd91000
  RCX = 000000000402d150  RDX = 0000000084e374c0
  RSP = 000000000402cf60  RBP = 000000000402e020
  RSI = 000000000402e008  RDI = 000000000402e028

   R8 = 0000000000001780   R9 = 000000007cd91000
  R10 = 0000000000000138  R11 = 0000000000000068
  R12 = 00000000000000bc  R13 = 000000000000000c
  R14 = 000000000000000c  R15 = 00000000000000bc

  RIP = 00000000b68ea342  EFL = 00010212

   CS = 0033   FS = 0053   GS = 002b

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00000000b68ea342   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\mkl.dll+26387266 xerbla+23942290
[  1] 0x00000000b5e639ea   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\mkl.dll+15350250 xerbla+12905274
[  2] 0x00000000b5e51ec1   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\mkl.dll+15277761 xerbla+12832785
[  3] 0x00000000b50af9c2   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\mkl.dll+00981442 mkl_cbwr_set+00610690
[  4] 0x00000000b50ab35c   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\mkl.dll+00963420 mkl_cbwr_set+00592668
[  5] 0x00000000b4fd9369   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\mkl.dll+00103273 dgemm+00000377
[  6] 0x00000000ee23cfd3 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\libmwmathlinalg.dll+00643027 UMFPACK_RealLUFactor::whackSymbolic+00115187
[  7] 0x00000000ee23e5fe C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\libmwmathlinalg.dll+00648702 UMFPACK_RealLUFactor::whackSymbolic+00120862
[  8] 0x00000000ee2c631e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\libmwmathlinalg.dll+01205022 ssmult+00110158
[  9] 0x00000000ee2c61cb C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\libmwmathlinalg.dll+01204683 ssmult+00109819
[ 10] 0x00000000ee2c652a C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\libmwmathlinalg.dll+01205546 ssmult+00110682
[ 11] 0x0000000004f52f5e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00077662 mdLogging::log_function_exit+00000110
[ 12] 0x0000000004f5295c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00076124 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000476
[ 13] 0x000000000510ce2c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00642604 inPublishWSEvents+00010700
[ 14] 0x000000000509bda6 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00179622 in_is_matlab_function+00124246
[ 15] 0x00000000050cbbea C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00375786 inGetCurrentWS+00147450
[ 16] 0x000000000508f19c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00127388 in_is_matlab_function+00072012
[ 17] 0x0000000005089f95 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00106389 in_is_matlab_function+00051013
[ 18] 0x000000000515684f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00944207 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::MCOSClassID+00000991
[ 19] 0x00000000051567b1 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00944049 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::MCOSClassID+00000833
[ 20] 0x00000000050cda75 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00383605 inGetCurrentWS+00155269
[ 21] 0x00000000050cce8c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00380556 inGetCurrentWS+00152220
[ 22] 0x00000000050cb6e9 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00374505 inGetCurrentWS+00146169
[ 23] 0x0000000004f52694 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00075412 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000548
[ 24] 0x0000000004f52a7e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00076414 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000766
[ 25] 0x0000000005089597 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00103831 in_is_matlab_function+00048455
[ 26] 0x000000000508a1ab C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00106923 in_is_matlab_function+00051547
[ 27] 0x000000000515684f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00944207 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::MCOSClassID+00000991
[ 28] 0x00000000051567b1 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00944049 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::MCOSClassID+00000833
[ 29] 0x00000000050cda75 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00383605 inGetCurrentWS+00155269
[ 30] 0x00000000050cce8c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00380556 inGetCurrentWS+00152220
[ 31] 0x00000000050cb6e9 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00374505 inGetCurrentWS+00146169
[ 32] 0x0000000004f52694 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00075412 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000548
[ 33] 0x0000000004f52a7e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00076414 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000766
[ 34] 0x0000000005089597 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00103831 in_is_matlab_function+00048455
[ 35] 0x00000000051a31a7 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+01257895 inIsKeyword+00027799
[ 36] 0x000000000508b69a C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00112282 in_is_matlab_function+00056906
[ 37] 0x000000000515684f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00944207 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::MCOSClassID+00000991
[ 38] 0x00000000051567b1 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00944049 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::MCOSClassID+00000833
[ 39] 0x00000000050cda75 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00383605 inGetCurrentWS+00155269
[ 40] 0x00000000050cce8c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00380556 inGetCurrentWS+00152220
[ 41] 0x00000000050cb6e9 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00374505 inGetCurrentWS+00146169
[ 42] 0x0000000004f52757 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00075607 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000743
[ 43] 0x0000000004f52a7e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00076414 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000766
[ 44] 0x0000000005089597 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00103831 in_is_matlab_function+00048455
[ 45] 0x00000000051a31a7 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+01257895 inIsKeyword+00027799
[ 46] 0x000000000508b69a C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00112282 in_is_matlab_function+00056906
[ 47] 0x000000000515684f C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00944207 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::MCOSClassID+00000991
[ 48] 0x00000000051567b1 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00944049 MathWorks::MException::MExceptionEnvelope::MCOSClassID+00000833
[ 49] 0x00000000050cda75 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00383605 inGetCurrentWS+00155269
[ 50] 0x00000000050cce8c C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00380556 inGetCurrentWS+00152220
[ 51] 0x00000000050cb6e9 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00374505 inGetCurrentWS+00146169
[ 52] 0x0000000004f52757 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00075607 Mfh_file::dispatch_fh+00000743
[ 53] 0x0000000004f52a7e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_dispatcher.dll+00076414 Mfunction_handle::dispatch+00000766
[ 54] 0x000000000515b268 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00963176 inAnonymousFunction+00000360
[ 55] 0x000000000515b864 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00964708 inAnonymousFunction+00001892
[ 56] 0x000000000515ba25 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00965157 inAnonymousFunction+00002341
[ 57] 0x000000000515b9f2 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00965106 inAnonymousFunction+00002290
[ 58] 0x000000000515b9a7 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00965031 inAnonymousFunction+00002215
[ 59] 0x000000000510f6bd C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00652989 inGetCallersWorkSpace+00001805
[ 60] 0x000000000510854d C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00623949 inEvalCmdWithLocalReturn+00000285
[ 61] 0x0000000005108471 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\m_interpreter.dll+00623729 inEvalCmdWithLocalReturn+00000065
[ 62] 0x00000000fb5fe82d C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\libmwbridge.dll+00059437 mnGetPrompt+00002717
[ 63] 0x00000000fb5ff2a9 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\libmwbridge.dll+00062121 mnParser+00000745
[ 64] 0x00000000fd0e13d4   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00398292 mcrInstance::mnParser_on_interpreter_thread+00000036
[ 65] 0x00000000fd0a9757   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00169815 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00019751
[ 66] 0x00000000fd0a9793   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00169875 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00019811
[ 67] 0x00000000fd0a9f91   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00171921 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00021857
[ 68] 0x00000000fab5d216   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00512534 UIW_AttachThreadInput+00001270
[ 69] 0x00000000fab5caa5   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00510629 wsd_to_MSW+00004373
[ 70] 0x00000000fab5cb29   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00510761 wsd_to_MSW+00004505
[ 71] 0x00007ffa095ebb5a                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00572250 BroadcastSystemMessageExA+00000558
[ 72] 0x00007ffa09563785                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00014213 MsgWaitForMultipleObjects+00000229
[ 73] 0x00007ffa095637f6                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00014326 MsgWaitForMultipleObjects+00000342
[ 74] 0x00007ffa09773034                      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+00602164 KiUserCallbackDispatcher+00000036
[ 75] 0x00007ffa09562f7a                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00012154 PeekMessageW+00000202
[ 76] 0x00007ffa09567bd3                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00031699 GetMessageA+00000243
[ 77] 0x00007ffa09567b7f                     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll+00031615 GetMessageA+00000159
[ 78] 0x00000000fab09bdb   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00170971 UIW_ShowMenuItem+00005179
[ 79] 0x00000000fab5db52   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\uiw.dll+00514898 UIW_SuspendAttachThreadInput+00000466
[ 80] 0x0000000100122c83 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01256579 services::system_events::PpeDispatchHook::dispatchOne+00032291
[ 81] 0x000000010012e6f5 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01304309 sysq::addProcessPendingEventsUnitTestHook+00005813
[ 82] 0x000000010012e7a0 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01304480 sysq::addProcessPendingEventsUnitTestHook+00005984
[ 83] 0x0000000100130595 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01312149 sysq::getCondition+00004629
[ 84] 0x0000000100131f52 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\libmwservices.dll+01318738 svWS_ProcessPendingEvents+00000162
[ 85] 0x00000000fd0aa6ad   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00173741 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00023677
[ 86] 0x00000000fd0ab31a   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00176922 mcr::runtime::setInterpreterThreadToCurrent+00026858
[ 87] 0x00000000fd0a2f75   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00143221 mcr_process_events+00007557
[ 88] 0x00000000fd0a4882   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\mcr.dll+00149634 mcr_process_events+00013970
[ 89] 0x000000000810b49d C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\MVMLocal.dll+00177309 mvm_server::inproc::LocalFactory::terminate+00048141
[ 90] 0x00000000fa8fa27a   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\mvm.dll+00828026 mvm::detail::initLocalMvmHack+00000490
[ 91] 0x00000000fa8fa838   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\mvm.dll+00829496 mvm::detail::SessionImpl::privateSession+00000376
[ 92] 0x00000000fa8faa88   C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\mvm.dll+00830088 mvm::detail::SessionImpl::privateSession+00000968
[ 93] 0x000000014000630d C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\MATLAB.exe+00025357
[ 94] 0x0000000140007dd0 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64\MATLAB.exe+00032208
[ 95] 0x00007ffa072e16ad                   C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL+00005805 BaseThreadInitThunk+00000013
[ 96] 0x00007ffa096f5444                      C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+00087108 RtlUserThreadStart+00000052


If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
    http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/

A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.

Thank you for your help.
```

Comment: Can you add the full error message to your question?

Comment: The crash dump file message was added.

Comment: I recommend to follow the advice at the end, contact the support.